# Bluetooth mouse not reconnecting after booting to Windows

Tags: dual-boot, mouse, bluetooth

I have a Microsoft Sculpt Comfort bluetooth mouse used on a dual boot system (Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 7).

When I connect and pair the mouse on one of the OSs, everything is fine and the mouse is auto-reconnected the next time I boot.

However, if I reboot on the other system and connect/pair the mouse on it, when I switch back to the first OS, the mouse is not recognized anymore and I have to delete it from the devices list then re-pair it to get it to connect. It's the same from Windows to Linux, or from Linux to Windows.

It's not a big deal since it works, but having to delete/reconnect the bluetooth device each time I reboot is quite unpleasant. Have you any idea to avoid this?

Comment: This may be a limitation of the device. I have a small bluetooth keyboard and I have it paired  with one pc .. I removed it and put it in another pc and paired it with that... and when I put it in the original PC I had to pair it again. same thing happened if I tried to pair it with my phone ... every time I have to pair it I have to enter a code .. since that code is different for each machine and I believe my device only stores the last used code.. it forces to pair again each time.

Comment: Try to use the same key see here http://askubuntu.com/questions/253949/how-can-i-avoid-having-to-pair-my-bluetooth-mouse-all-the-time