# Problems reconnecting Apple bluetooth devices Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, mac

I have Mac OS X El Capitan and Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my iMac 27" (Late 2012). There is no problem  connecting my  bluetooth keyboard and trackpad in Ubuntu. I can reboot in ubuntu over and over again. Still works fine on bootup! However, if I then boot in to OS X I have to pair them there again, and if I then restart in Ubuntu they have to be reconnected again. (I do this with a usb optical mouse.) Very disturbing. Help?

Comment: This is generally how BT pairing works, your Ubuntu and OSX installs are different devices and the HIDs will need to be manually re-paired when you change os. Otherwise, other devices near by will constantly be hijacking your HIDs.

Answer (score 0):

most BT mouse and keyboard can only be paired to one computer (one OS to be specific)
I had the same with Win/Ubuntu and MS Sculpt mouse

You can try to use the same key see here
[How can I avoid having to pair my bluetooth mouse all the time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253949/how-can-i-avoid-having-to-pair-my-bluetooth-mouse-all-the-time)