# Magic Mouse and Apple Keyboard on Ubuntu-macOS dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, keyboard, mouse, bluetooth, mac

I've installed Ubuntu 17.10 on my Imac (mid 2011) next to mac OS Sierra, managing this dual boot with rEFind 0.11.2. I'm using the original keyboard and the Magic Mouse, connected using bluetooth. The problem is that when I configure them in mac OS, Linux doesn't recognize theme and I'm not able to log in and *vice versa*. Do you know how could I resolve that problem? I'm not so expert, even if I've used Ubuntu for a long time on a laptop (it was pretty simpler than today).

Thanks to everyone, I really appreciate your help. I'm sorry for possible mistakes but I'm not mother tongue.

Answer (score 1):

Number 5 no longer works for Monterey, MacOS.
Do the following instead :
Open the Keychain Access application.
Type "bluetooth" in the search field, then double-click on the latest MobileBluetooth entry. A new window opens.
From that new window, you will see your device address in the Account field (xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx). Write it somewhere else.
Then, in the same window, tick Show password and enter your credentials (twice).
The now revealed password is in fact a full XML file. Click on (i.e. highlight) the field, press Option + A (capital) then copy-paste it to a document.  It is very long so most of it is hidden.  Keep on moving forward and more appears.
Below <key LinkKey</key, the value between the string>xx-xx-xx-xx</string is the link key.  It no longer needs to be reversed to add to Ubuntu.
Then boot into Ubuntu and follow the guide.

Answer (score 0):

**Apple keyboard**
Connect with the cable and also keep the "slide-switch" in the switched on position.

**Mouse:**

1. Initially you will have to use a wired or 2.4Gz adapter mouse.
2. `sudo apt-get install -y blueman`
3. connect your mouse using the GUI and also set it as trusted device.

Comment: The problem is that also keyboard doesn't have a cable option

Answer (score 0):

@LaBarbaGrande

It's been a long while since you posted. In case you (or others finding this thread) haven't yet found a solution to make persistent bluetooth pairings I would like to point to what seems to be the by far best resource on resolving this issue:

[How can I use the same Bluetooth keyboard and mouse with both macOS and Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/948417/how-can-i-use-the-same-bluetooth-keyboard-and-mouse-with-both-macos-and-ubuntu)

FYI I am facing the same challenge as you. At this point I unfortunately haven't been able finish the guide (got stuck at STEP 6 as I was unable to locate the shared folder resource referred to in the guide + my limited knowledge of the subject and has prevented me from seeking out possible workarounds).

But it does seem like the best resource thus far so figured you and other might benefit.

Comment: FYI as a new user here I just found out that I don't have reputation required to leave a comment at the resource linked to above. In case somebody may be able to clarify I've c/p the comment that addresses the specifics of my issue her instead:

@Digital Trauma: Thanks for sharing your solution. 

I'm trying to follow the recipe kindly put forward here. 

At step 6 the terminal command refers to a shared. Issuing the command I get a no such dir /file err. When I cd into /Volumes 4T does not exist. 

Hoping you or anybody with deeper knowledge can point towards a workaround?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.