# Wireless keyboard and mouse don't work when switching OS in dual boot

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, xubuntu, windows, bluetooth

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 alongside my Windows 10 and apparently I can't have my Microsoft keyboard and mouse connected with both OS without pairing them every time. This is so annoying I can't even describe how much.

I need your help with that if you have any clue for a solution it will be awesome!

Thanks!!

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/948417/how-can-i-use-the-same-bluetooth-keyboard-and-mouse-with-both-macos-and-ubuntu?rq=1 for the approach of copying a bluetooth pairing key from another Os into Ubuntu.

Comment: Is this related to Ubuntu and Windows as well?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/253949/how-can-i-avoid-having-to-pair-my-bluetooth-mouse-all-the-time for windows. Each pairing generates a unique key, so you have to manually copy the key (buried in the Microsoft registry), from one to the other to have the same key.

Comment: Or get a Logitech wireless mouse/keyboard that use the Logitech Unifying USB receiver. You can pair them in one OS, and have them still paired in the other OS. Install `solaar` in Ubuntu to do the pairing, and Logitech `Unifying Software` on Windows.

Comment: @heynnema, can I pair my wireless keyboard+ mouse now to a normal USB that I have ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: @heynnema I'm taking a regular USB for pairing my current keyboard and mouse. How can I do it?

Comment: I still don't understand what you're asking. Please be more specific.

Comment: @heynnema again lol haha, I'm taking a normal USB from a store, and Im asking how can I use it as an adapter (like the Logitech you said before) to connect my keyboard+mouse .... Read my question again if you don't understand ,thanka again

Comment: re: "taking a normal USB from a store" so do you mean a standard USB keyboard and a standard USB mouse? I thought your question said "without pairing them every time" which suggests a bluetooth or RF keyboard and mouse. If you're using a Microsoft wireless keyboard/mouse, it uses its own USB receiver, and can only use that receiver. The Logitech I quoted replaces the Microsoft USB receiver, and keyboard, and mouse entirely. Do I have it right now?