# Every time need to remove and pair Bluetooth audio devices in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, bluetooth, hardware, bluetooth-speaker

I paired the Logitec Bluetooth audio adapter and Mi Bluetooth audio adapter to my laptop. But every time I restarted the laptop is showing the devices are disconnected. I need to remove the device and pair again will work. It was happening on Ubuntu 18.04. So I fresh install 20.04. But the issue not resolved. But it is automatically connected in Windows 10. There are no such issues. So it is clear that it is an issue related to Ubuntu irrespective of versions.

I am using HP Pavilion DK0045TX gaming laptop with the below configurations

- Intel i5 9300H
- 16GB ram
- Nvidia GTX 1050

For more hardware details https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c06362565

After googling I can see somebody has the same issue. But no solutions are working for them and me.

Comment: cause you have dual boot, this here would be the solution https://askubuntu.com/questions/253949/how-can-i-avoid-having-to-pair-my-bluetooth-mouse-all-the-time.. be aware that if you using windows 10 and you set the volume to 20, then on ubuntu you will have also very low volume